# Can I change back color of gridview row which is programmatically databinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
```

and I bind it on page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from table"
}
```

and at the table I have a field 'date'

```
+-----+
|date |
+-----+
|date1|
+-----+
|date2|
+-----+
```

and I want do that control---> if date1 < now gridviewrows backcolor = red

I did it this way

```
protected void GridViewServicesList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = 
        Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[indexOfDateField].Text);//returns null!!!
    if(date < DateTime.Now)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

and this is not working, What should I do?
**Firstly I can't even access date. I mean the variable DateTime date is null...** 
By the way
this is not my real code, I write it for basically understanding.

Comment: Try setting the background-color of the cells instead of the row

Comment: but date is null so cant do it too, I cant access 'date'. Maybe I am in wrong event??

Comment: Are you sure `date` is null? Or does `DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[indexOfDateField].Text);` generate an error?

Comment: yes I am sure it is null no err.

Comment: You can itterate through the collecting and change in the pre-render event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date1 label is in a TemplateField, the use the sample below.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        //Reference the date1 label in Gridviews template field
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label date1 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Row.FindControl("date1");
        GridViewRow myRow = e.Row;
        //set back color to green if incident category is hazard
        if (date1 < DateTime.Now)
             {
               e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.SpringGreen;
            }   
    }
}
```