# make datagrid view row color change depending on the query result

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a grid view like this:
[image]

then i am executing one query like this:

```
select t.TBarcode as Carid from Khanger_tbl k
inner join transaction_tbl t on k.transactid=t.transactID
 where tid=20 and requested=1 and delivered=0 and DATEDIFF(n, CAST(paydate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) >=8
```

result

```
carid
457
477
```

the result is getting some carid...if the result car id matching the datagrid view car Id,,then i want to make particular row yellow color..
ex: the query result i got 457,477...then i want to make that particular row of the carid in the grid view as yellow color..

how i can do this?

Comment: take a look at that.Seems smilar. hope help you... 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21261048/1969386

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you must do that query before grid will be loaded (or reload it after query) and make event handler for "onItemDataBound" where you will be checking if value from first column is in your list of car Ids and then making whole row yellow :)

Comment: i am working with timer..each 20 second i am reloading the grid view..so when ever that result carid matching with my datagrid view carid,,then i want to show particular row yellow.

Comment: So make event handler for itemDataBound :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx